# sqlcode -117 - ibm mainframe

Tags: db2, db2-zos

The first image is of the table. I keep getting an error saying what im trying to insert into the table is not the same as what is in
the table. I

The second image is where I have inserted into the table.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIFw6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD8Pv.png

Comment: DSNT408I SQLCODE = -117, ERROR:  THE NUMBER OF ASSIGNED VALUES IS NOT THE SAME AS THE NUMBER OF SPECIFIED OR IMPLIED COLUMNS                              DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42802 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                        
DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNXOIN SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR             
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = -111  0  0  -1  0  0 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION   
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'FFFFFF91'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'
         X'00000000'  X'00000000' SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with [tag:mysql]. Are you sure you have tagged this question accurately?

Comment: You create table __INVOICE_P__  but you insert into __INVOICE__  .   Fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

the screenshots show that you are inserting into a different table than the one you are creating.

You create table INVOICE_P but you insert into INVOICE.

Most likely the table INVOICE has a different number or type of columns than INVOICE_P, so Db2 will throw the sqlcode -117 exception.

Try inserting into INVOICE_P  instead.